# The Slide not auto but click next or prev

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I downloaded a soure code of a slide jquery. In html code. When I set div width to a pixel (ex : 1300px;), slider will play normaly. But, when I set div width to % (ex : width: 100%;), slider will not autoplay before I next or prev slider.
How can I fix it ?
P/S : I wanna fix size slider to 100% (now, the slide just fit to 1366px), how can.
Hope your help. Thank you and sorry for my English.
Soure is :

CSS :

```
.captionOrange, .captionBlack
    {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .captionOrange
    {
        background: #EB5100;
        background-color: rgba(235, 81, 0, 0.6);
    }
    .captionBlack
    {
        font-size:16px;
        background: #000;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    a.captionOrange, A.captionOrange:active, A.captionOrange:visited
    {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.captionOrange:hover
    {
        color: #eb5100;
        text-decoration: underline;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.7);
    }
    .bricon
    {
        background: url(../img/browser-icons.png);
    }
```

Scrip :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        {$Duration: 1000, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }
        , { $Duration: 1200, y: 0.3, $Cols: 2, $During: { $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Outside: true }
        , { $Duration: 1000, x: -1, y: 2, $Rows: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Row: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.85} }
        //, { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: 4, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 11, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
        //, { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: 4, y: -4, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} }
        , { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.3, y: -0.3, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: -3, y: 1, $Rows: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Row: 28 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} }
        , { $Duration: 1200, y: -1, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Top: [0.5, 0.5], $Clip: [0, 0.5] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $ChessMode: { $Column: 12 }, $ScaleClip: 0.5 }
        //, { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationSwirl, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3, $Top: 2.5} }
        //, { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} }
        //, { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 20, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} }
        , { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Top: [0.2, 0.8], $Zoom: [0.2, 0.8], $Rotate: [0.2, 0.8] }, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} }
        , { $Duration: 1500, y: -0.5, $Delay: 60, $Cols: 24, $SlideOut: true, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationCircle, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Round: { $Top: 1.5} }
        , { $Duration: 1000, $Delay: 30, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs, $Assembly: 2050, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }
        , { $Duration: 1200, $Delay: 20, $Clip: 3, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 260, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
        //, { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Delay: 80, $Cols: 10, $Rows: 4, $Clip: 15, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Top: [0.2, 0.8] }, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15, $Row: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} }
        ];
        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["TR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["L|IB"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R|IB"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T|IB"] = { $Duration: 1200, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 3, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|TB"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 12, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };

        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|T"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 4, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
         _CaptionTransitions["WV|B"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.2, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Left: 1.5} };

        _CaptionTransitions["TORTUOUS|VB"] = { $Duration: 1800, y: -0.2, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Top: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["LISTH|R"] = { $Duration: 1500, x: -0.8, $Clip: 1, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic, $ScaleClip: 0.8, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.4, 0.6], $Clip: [0, 0.4], $Opacity: [0.4, 0.6]} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|360"] = { $Duration: 900, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["T|IE*IE"] = { $Duration: 1800, y: 0.8, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: -1.5, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutElastic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInElastic, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutElastic }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Zoom: [0, 0.8], $Opacity: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };

        _CaptionTransitions["RTTS|R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTTS|T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} };

        _CaptionTransitions["DDGDANCE|RB"] = { $Duration: 1800, x: -0.3, y: -0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["DDG|TR"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.3, y: 0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 0.8} };

        _CaptionTransitions["FLTTR|R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.2, y: -0.1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };
        _CaptionTransitions["FLTTRWN|LT"] = { $Duration: 1800, x: 0.5, y: 0.2, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.7], $Top: [0.1, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["ATTACK|BR"] = { $Duration: 1500, x: -0.1, y: -0.5, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7], $Top: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Left: 1.3} };

        _CaptionTransitions["FADE"] = { $Duration: 900, $Opacity: 2 };
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  
            $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            
            $PauseOnHover: 3,                                   
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          
            $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          
            $SlideDuration: 800,                                
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           
                $ShowLink: true                                    
            },
            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 
            },
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               
                $AutoCenter: 2,                                 
                $Steps: 1                                       
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 
                $Steps: 1,                                      
                $Lanes: 1,                                      
                $SpacingX: 4,                                   
                $SpacingY: 4,                                   
                $Orientation: 1                                 
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 980), 300));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    });
</script>
```

HTML Code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: absolute; width: 100%;
    height: 590px; overflow: hidden; display: block;">
     <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block; background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%; height:100%;"> 
        </div> 
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; background-position: center top; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1366px; height: 590px;
        overflow: hidden; display: block;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/home/a1.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="CLIP|LR" du="1500" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:500px; height:30px;"> 
            Touch swipe and responsive javascript image slider
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="L|IB" t2=L d=-900 class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:360px; top: 130px; width:60px; height:30px;"> 
            comes
            </div> 
            <div u=caption t="RTT|360" d=-200 class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:360px; top: 180px; width:60px; height:30px;"> 
            with
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="DDGDANCE|RB" t2="RTT|10" d=-1800 du=3800 class="captionOrange" style="position:absolute; left:560px; top: 110px; width:200px; height:120px; text-align: left;">
                &nbsp; Banner Slider<br />

            </div>
            <div u=caption t="T|IE*IE" d=-1600 du=3800 t2="B" class="captionOrange" style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 310px; width:330px; height:30px;">
                slideshow and responsive slider ...
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="ZMF|10" t2="B" d=-1300 style="position:absolute;left:420px;top:280px;width:90px;height:40px;font-size:36px;color:#fff;line-height:40px;">390+</div>
            <div u="caption" t="CLIP|L" d=-300 style="position:absolute;left:520px;top:280px;width:160px;height:40px;font-size:36px;color:#fff;line-height:40px; text-align: center;">caption</div>
            <a class="captionOrange" u="caption" t="CLIP|L" d=-300 href="http://www.jssor.com/" style="position:absolute;left:720px;top:280px;width:220px;height:40px;font-size:36px;color:#fff;line-height:40px;">transitions</a>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <img u="image" src="../img/home/02.jpg" />
            <a class="captionOrange" href="http://www.jssor.com/development/" style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 630px; width: 250px; height: 30px;">360+ Slideshow Transitions</a>
            <div u=caption t="CLIP|LR" t2="B" du="2000" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 300px; width:500px; height:30px;"> 
            Jssor Slider is one of best performance sliders
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="FADE" t2="B" d=-450 class=captionBlack style="position: absolute; left:700px;top:120px;width:200px;height:90px;">
                    No-JQuery<br />
                    Independent<br />
                    Javascript Code
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="T|IB" t2="R" d=-600 class=captionOrange style="position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 720px; width: 160px;
                height: 90px;  line-height: 90px;">
                Compress
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|T" t2="T" d=-450 style="position:absolute;left:505px;top:40px;width:200px;height:30px;font-size:18px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;text-align:center;">Size&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;CPU Usage</div>
            <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|R" d=-300 style="position:absolute;left:325px;top:90px;width:350px;height:30px;font-size:18px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">Slider with Slideshow&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 23KB&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ~4%</div>
            <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|R" d=-300 style="position:absolute;left:325px;top:140px;width:350px;height:30px;font-size:18px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">Slider with Caption&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 18KB&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ~4%</div>
            <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|R" d=-300 style="position:absolute;left:325px;top:190px;width:350px;height:30px;font-size:18px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">Slider&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;17KB&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ~1%</div>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <img u="image" src="../img/home/03.jpg" />
            <a class="captionOrange" href="http://www.jssor.com" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; right: 30px; width: 200px;">30+ Templates</a>
            <div u=caption t="T" t2=NO style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top:30px; width:600px; height:90px; color: #fff; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;"> 
                Jssor Slider is touch swipe image slideshow with 360+ javascript slideshow effects.<br />
                When touch Jssor Slider,<br />
                it will freeze and then move to the direction that finger swipes to.
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="L" d=-750 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 300px; width:130px; height:30px;"> 
            Jssor slider
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="CLIP|L" t2=B d=-450 class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:160px; top: 300px; width:30px; height:30px;"> 
            is
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="DDG|TR" t2="TORTUOUS|VB" d=-750 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:200px; top: 300px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            most scalable photo slideshow
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="RTT|10" d=-450 class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:430px; top: 240px; width:30px; height:30px;"> 
            for
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="TORTUOUS|VB" d=-750 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:590px; top: 220px; width:80px; height:30px;"> 
            photo
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="T" d=-450 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:720px; top: 200px; width:80px; height:30px;"> 
            image
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="FLTTR|R" t2="B" d=-600 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:560px; top: 300px; width:80px; height:30px;"> 
            picture
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="ATTACK|BR" d=-600 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:760px; top: 310px; width:80px; height:30px;"> 
            content
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="FLTTRWN|LT" d=-900 style="position:absolute;left:460px;top:160px;width:130px;height:30px;font-size:28px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">html code</div>
            <div u="caption" t="RTTS|R" d=-900 style="position:absolute;left:760px;top:120px;width:130px;height:30px;font-size:28px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">web page</div>
            <div u="caption" t="R|IB" t2=R d=-900 style="position:absolute;left:860px;top:250px;width:60px;height:30px;font-size:28px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">text</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/home/04.jpg" />
            <div u=caption t="RTTS|T" d=-300 t2="B" class=captionOrange style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 330px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            one of the most reliable sliders
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="T|IB" t2="T" d=-300 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 100px; width:130px; height:30px;"> 
            All browsers
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="T|IB" t2=L d=-900 class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:60px; top: 170px; width:100px; height:30px;"> 
            supported
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d=-600 class=bricon style="position:absolute; top:50px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class=bricon style="position:absolute; top:100px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -30px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class=bricon style="position:absolute; top:150px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -60px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class=bricon style="position:absolute; top:200px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -90px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="WV|B" t2="T" d="-1100" class=bricon style="position:absolute; top:250px; left: 220px; width:30px; height:30px; background-position: -120px 0px;"></div>
            <div u="caption" t="LISTH|R" t2="CLIP|TB" d=-600 class=captionOrange style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 280px; width: 180px;
                height: 250px; text-align: left; line-height: 50px;">
                    &nbsp; Chrome&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 3+<br />
                    &nbsp; Firerfox&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2+<br />
                    &nbsp; IE&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 6+<br />
                    &nbsp; Safari&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 3.1+<br />
                    &nbsp; Opera&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;10+
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="TR" t2="T" d=-900 class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:700px; top: 40px; width:130px; height:30px;"> 
            All devices
            </div>
            <div u=caption t="R" t2=R d=-900 class="captionBlack"  style="position:absolute; left:780px; top: 55px; width:100px; height:30px;"> 
            supported
            </div>
            <div u="caption" t="T|IB" d=-900 style="position:absolute;left:525px;top:90px;width:220px;height:30px;font-size:28px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">Windows Phone</div>
            <div u="caption" t="T|IB" t2="ZMF|10" d=-900 style="position:absolute;left:560px;top:160px;width:120px;height:30px;font-size:28px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">Android</div>
            <div u="caption" t="T|IB" t2=R d=-900 style="position:absolute;left:760px;top:140px;width:60px;height:30px;font-size:28px;color:#fff;line-height:30px;">iOS</div>
            <img u="caption" t="T|IB" t2=B d=-900 src="../img/home/moc-iphone.png" style="position:absolute;left:600px;top:230px;width:120px;height:80px;" />
            <img u="caption" t="RTTL|BR" d=-450 src="../img/home/moc-ipad.png" style="position:absolute;left:750px;top:220px;width:77px;height:100px;" />
        </div>

        <style>

        </style>


    </div> 

    <style>
        .jssorb03 div, .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av
        {
            background: url(../img/b03.png) no-repeat;
            overflow:hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .jssorb03 div { background-position: -5px -4px; }
        .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -4px; }
        .jssorb03 .av { background-position: -65px -4px; }
        .jssorb03 .dn, .jssorb03 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -4px; }
    </style>
    <div u="navigator" class="jssorb03" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; left: 6px;">
        <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 21px; HEIGHT: 21px; text-align:center; line-height:21px; color:White; font-size:12px;"><div u="numbertemplate"></div></div>
    </div>
    <style>

        .jssora20l, .jssora20r, .jssora20ldn, .jssora20rdn
        {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            background: url(../img/a20.png) no-repeat;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .jssora20l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
        .jssora20r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
        .jssora20l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
        .jssora20r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
        .jssora20ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
        .jssora20rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
    </style>
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora20l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
    </span>
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora20r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
    </span>
    <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Image Slider</a>
</div> 
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you remove irrelevant pieces of your code so this is easier to read?

Comment: The original size should be always in pixel. But you can scale slider to any size.